# PHP implode with a PDO SQL LIKE query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to run a query with an array in it. I imploded the array but I cant use the sql IN function because i will use a LIKE function. So this was the solution I thought off:

```
$soort = $_POST['soort'];

$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM antwoorden_259 WHERE vraag4 LIKE :soort 
                    AND vraag3 LIKE :merk 
                    AND vraag16 BETWEEN :prijsvan AND :prijstot 
                    AND vraag5 BETWEEN :minkm AND :maxkm 
                    AND vraag8 BETWEEN :vermogenvan AND :vermogentot 
                    AND vraag9 LIKE :brandstof 
                    ORDER BY vraag3 ASC LIMIT 5"
                   );


$st->bindValue(':soort', implode(" OR ", $soort));
$st->bindValue(':merk', "%%");
$st->bindValue(':prijsvan', $prijs_particulier_van);
$st->bindValue(':prijstot', $prijs_particulier_tot);
$st->bindValue(':minkm', $minkm);
$st->bindValue(':maxkm', $maxkm);
$st->bindValue(':vermogenvan', $vermogenvan);
$st->bindValue(':vermogentot', $vermogentot);
$st->bindValue(':brandstof', $brandstof);
$st->execute();
```

Im sorry for the dutch words, please ignore the bind values except for the :soort one. Basically what I am trying to do is to split my array $soort into a string like this: truck OR car OR boat, etc. The user can select values in checkboxes on a different page.

I cant seem to figure out why the final query is not working, the implode does its thing and it does work when I manually try to use it in PHPMyAdmin.. Also the query does work when I select 1 checkbox, but it stops working when I select a second...

Can anyone help me? I probably forgot something.. It's been a long day!

The HTML:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="vrachtwagen" id="check-1" class="checked" name="soort[]">
    <label for="check-1" class="">
        <span class="flt_lt">Vrachtwagen</span>
        <span class="flt_rt">5</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="trekker" name="soort[]" id="check-2">
    <label for="check-2" class="">
        <span class="flt_lt">Trekker</span>
        <span class="flt_rt">5</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="oplegger" name="soort[]" id="check-3" class="checked">
    <label for="check-3" class="">
        <span class="flt_lt">Oplegger</span>
        <span class="flt_rt">5</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="vrachtwagen" name="soort[]" id="check-4" class="checked">
    <label for="check-4" class="">
        <span class="flt_lt">Aanhanger</span>
        <span class="flt_rt">10</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: If you add `echo $st->errorInfo();` what does it say?

Comment: p.s. you could always convert the dutch words to english

Comment: Also, which checkboxes? Post all code that is relevant to the question

Comment: Hi Jelmergu, I added the HTML. Also when I tried adding: print_r($st->errorInfo()) inbetween the bindvalue and execute, it returns an empty array..

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some product specific SQL there.

Comment: it should be after the execute, that is when the errors get created by the database

Comment: Hey @jarlh, I am using MySQL

Comment: @Jelmergu I just tried that and still got an empty array. Could it be that I am adding it without '' around the values? Or maybe that the OR is within a string and isnt seen by the DBMS?

Comment: see the answer of ampehtamachine below. With a small hint though, execute accepts an array of parameters, as long as the parameters don't have to be a certain type(int for the LIMIT clause for example) it is kinder to the eyes in my opinion to use that

Answer (score 0):

Your `soort` parameter is getting inserted into the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM antwoorden_259
    WHERE vraag4 LIKE 'trekker OR oplegger' [...]
```

If I gather your goal correctly, you'll need to separate these out into separate bound parameters so they're inserted into the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM antwoorden_259
    WHERE vraag4 LIKE 'trekker'
    OR vraag4 LIKE 'oplegger' [...]
```

When a query has a variable number of bound parameters, I find I need to use numerically-indexed parameters using `?` in the prepared SQL.

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM antwoorden_259 WHERE
    vraag4 LIKE ?
    OR vraag4 LIKE ?
");
$st->bindValue(1, $soort[0]);
$st->bindValue(2, $soort[1]);
```

(Adapting the query to a variable number of parameters has been left as an exercise for the reader.)

If your SQL dialect supports it, you could use a "LIKE in array" type operator like PostgreSQL supports: `WHERE somecolumn ~~* any(array['%some%', '%someelse']))`

Comment: Hey, do you mean adding it like this:

$st->bindValue(':soort', implode(' " OR vraag4 LIKE " ', $soort));

I tried this but it returns nothing..

Comment: @SebastianBoender No, you're still shoving them all into one parameter. You won't be able to do that. See revised answer.

Comment: I thought of that too, but the problem is is that this script will be executed onclick by AJAX. The soort array can contain anywhere between 1 and 4 values. Its different everytime... Any solution to this?

Comment: @SebastianBoender Dynamically construct your query based on the number of elements in your `soort` array?